# How to install dlib for python on mac?

Tags: python, macos, pip, dlib

I'm getting an error when trying to install dlib on Python 3.7 on macOS with

```
pip3 install dlib
```

I have installed CMake, so that is not the problem.
I'm getting these error messages:

```
Failed building wheel for dlib
```

and

```
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/j2/nvk5521j2vn9s1w95_0vlwkm0000gn/T/pip-install-ls2e_3mr/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/j2/nvk5521j2vn9s1w95_0vlwkm0000gn/T/pip-record-hy3hu262/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" 
failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/j2/nvk5521j2vn9s1w95_0vlwkm0000gn/T/pip-install-ls2e_3mr/dlib/
```

at the end in red. The reason I need dlib is to install face_recognition.

Comment: It installs successfully for me on python 3.7.2, pip3 19.0.2, cmake 3.13.4, dlib 19.16.0, and macOS 10.13.6. A few questions: (1) How did you install Python3 and CMake? (2) What is your MacOS version?

Comment: I installed CMake with `pip3 install cmake`. I am on macOS 10.14.3. I installed Python 3.7.2 from the website just a few days ago. I am using CMake 3.13.3

Comment: Right after un/reinstalling cmake via both brew and pip in multiple combos from loads of SO posts, including removing brew entirely and reinstalling, I downgraded from python3.11 (by brew removing it) and installed python 3.9.  `which python3.9` `which pip3.9` `pip install cmake` and `pip install dlib` and this finally worked.  `cmake --version` == 3.25..2

Comment: And then `pip install face_recognition` worked.  So basically it was a python upgrade that appeared to have broken my face_recognition scripting on my Monterey instance.

Answer (score 16):

I think there's more to the error message and it's probably related to CMake, either it's not installed properly or it's not compatible with the `pip3 install dlib`.

I suggest using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install Python3 (which includes pip3) and CMake. Homebrew manages the installation of packages, tools, libraries that might depend on system-related tools, paths, etc. It also prevents you from having to use `sudo` to install stuff on your system.

1. Install Homebrew

   - See the "*Install Homebrew*" section of https://brew.sh/
   - Basically:

     ```
     $ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
     ```
2. Install Python3 (and pip3) using Homebrew

   - See https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python
   - See Homebrew's formula for the latest Python3 ([python3.7](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python@3.7), [python3.8](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python@3.8), [python3.9](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python@3.9))
   - Basically do one of the following:

     ```
     $ brew install python@3.7  # or python@3.8 or python@3.9
     $ brew install python@3    # get whichever is the latest version
     ```
3. Check Python installation

   ```
   $ python3 -V
   $ python3 -m pip -V
   ```
4. Install CMake using Homebrew

   - See https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cmake
   - Basically:

     ```
     $ brew install cmake
     ```
5. Check CMake installation

   ```
   $ brew info cmake
   $ cmake --version
   ```
6. Finally, install dlib with `pip`

   ```
   $ python3 -m pip install dlib
   ```

---

If you don't want to use Homebrew (for some reason), you can try installing CMake for Mac directly using the installers (dmg or tar.gz) from here: https://cmake.org/download/.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install Homebrew from [here](https://brew.sh/)
2. A bunch of dependencies are needed for dlib:

   ```
   brew install cmake
   brew install boost
   brew install boost-python
   brew install dlib
   pip3 install numpy
   pip3 install scipy
   pip3 install scikit-image
   pip3 install dlib
   ```
3. If this does not work, try:

   ```
   python3 -m pip install dlib
   ```

Answer (score 3):

dlib is dependent on cmake so you need to install that first.
You just need to run following commands on your terminal:

```
$ brew install cmake 
$ pip install cmake 
$ brew install dlib 
$ pip install dlib
```

Comment: `pip install dlib` fails like it did from other solutions in my searching.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the conda-forge Dlib package by running

---

conda install -c conda-forge dlib

Conda-forge has made sure to resolve all the dependency conflicts, so I had no issues with the installation. They have pre-built binaries for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS, and Python 2.7 through 3.8. The current package (at the time of this writing) is based on Dlib v19.19.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade pip

$ pip3 install global

$ pip3 install cmake

$ pip3 install dlib
```

```
$ brew install dlib
```

```
$ sudo pip install dlib
```

Answer (score -1):

The only thing you need to do, I guess, is run pip3 install dlib with sudo.

sudo pip3 install dlib

Comment: This information is already included in other answers, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63791375/2359227). If you have nothing to add please just upvote the best answer. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)