# ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib on MacOS Catalina

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to get eye tracking on python. I've installed openCV and everything required except dlib. When I first tried it, It just went into a "Building wheel for setup.py" Loop. I've looked around on stackoverflow and I tried following [This Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54719496/installing-dlib-in-python-on-mac) to install it with homebrew, and I've tried using [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54714603/building-wheel-for-dlib-setup-py-loop) to log all the errors. By doing this I see a lot of warnings, but it gets to about 98% before failing and trying again. Here's what I'm using:

- MacOS Catalina Version 10.15.7
- Visual studio 2019(although I don't know if that matters)
- Python 3.8

I have CMAKE version 3.18.2(when running cmake --version)

If it helps, when I do pip install cmake it says it's already installed for python3.5, but will work for python 3.8.

Any tips would be appreciated. I can give more info aswell

Comment: Please show the entire stack trace.

Comment: The terminal cuts off from all the error, but here's some I found:   In file included from /tmp/pip-install-mu8me5bd/dlib/tools/python/src/face_recognition.cpp:4:
  In file included from /tmp/pip-install-mu8me5bd/dlib/tools/python/src/opaque_types.h:6:
  In file included from /tmp/pip-install-mu8me5bd/dlib/dlib/../dlib/python.h:6:
  In file included from /tmp/pip-install-mu8me5bd/dlib/dlib/../dlib/python/pybind_utils.h:6:
It's just stuff like this, except replacing the last part.